# Immediate implications of moving from 255.255.0.0 to 255.255.255.0 subnet mask?

Tags: networking, subnet

We currently have a network setup like this: 10.1.0.0 with a subnet mask of 255.255.0.0.

Nonetheless, the third octet was sorta/kinda used to identify the group of devices.  Example: 10.1.1.0 - 10.1.1.255 is used for servers.

Soon, we will migrate to a real 255.255.255.0 subnet mask (with corresponding VLANs).  What immediate implications should we see?  Example: would server 10.1.1.5/16 still be able to talk to 10.1.1.10/16, despite the fact that the network has been split into a /24?

To be clear: we have all intentions of very quickly correcting the subnet mask on all servers to 255.255.255.0.  I am just wondering what happens to communications before we get the correction made (or, more likely, we overlook some undocumented corrections for a while).

Answer (score 1):

Devices in the same (new) subnet will still be able to talk to each other.  But devices that will now be in different subnets will need a router to communicate.

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly why Proxy ARP was invented.

If you do the middlebox (switch/router) changes first, and configure the router to do Proxy ARP on all of the new subnets/VLANs, then you shouldn't have a problem. Hosts that haven't been reconfigured for the smaller subnet mask will still ARP for the IP addresses of hosts that are now on separate subnets, and the router, via Proxy ARP, will respond on behalf of the host on the other subnet/VLAN, and take care of forwarding the traffic between those subnets/VLANs even for machines that still have the /16 subnet mask.

Comment: If somebody has to ask this basic ipv4 question, I seriously doubt that he/she is able to properly setup proxy-arp. In such a situation messing with proxy-arp might do more harm than good...

Comment: @Tonny Proxy ARP should just be a per-interface checkbox in the router's settings UI. If some vendor's equipment makes it harder than that, then they have serious UI design deficiencies.

Comment: Are you serious? That is only a very basic default setup. To use it properly in a large multi-vlan setup configuration (especially with redundant L2 and L3 switches and load-balancers) it gets quite tricky real quick. And from the sound of the question the asker may be in such a situation, with the actual network backbone being controlled by another department. Chances are he deals with servers (and tries to understand the implications), but the network itself is managed by another party.